What is the value of the following contour integral?
In the realm of complex analysis, I am delving into the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh^2(u)} \, du
$$
with a keen focus on leveraging the residue theorem to evaluate it. I'm particularly interested in dissecting its computation for distinct signs of $p$.
While I grasp the fundamental principles of the method, I am grappling with identifying the poles and computing residues, especially given the shifts in behavior for $p > 0$ and $p < 0$. Could someone provide a step-by-step guidance on computing this integral for both positive and negative $p$, elucidating the selection of the integration contour and the residue computation process?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What function of a complex variable do you want to apply the residue theorem to? Which closed contours can you use which will allow you to apply the residue theorem to that function in order to calculate this integral?

We can use the rectangular contour in the complex plane to find the general expression for
$$I_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh^nu}du, \,n=1, 2, 3...$$
Let's choose $\alpha<1$ and consider
$$J(\alpha)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha^nI_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\alpha}{\cosh u}\,\frac1{1-\frac{\alpha}{\cosh u}}e^{-ipu}du=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\alpha}{\cosh u-\alpha}e^{-ipu}du$$
$J(\alpha)$ is the generating function for $I_n$:
$$I_n=\frac1{n!}\frac{\partial^n}{\partial \alpha^n}J(\alpha)\,\bigg|_{\alpha=0}$$
Let's also take for a while $\alpha=\cos\beta$, where $\beta\in(0;\frac\pi2]$.
Integration of the function $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{\cos\beta}{\cosh z-\cos\beta}e^{-ipz}$ along the rectangular contour in the complex plane $\,\,-R\to R\to R+2\pi i\to-R+2\pi i\to-R;\,R\to\infty\,\,$ gives us
$$J(\alpha)\Big(1-e^{2\pi p}\Big)=2\pi i\sum\operatorname{Res}f(z)$$
The function $f(z)$ has two simple poles inside our contour: at $z=i\beta$ and $z=2\pi i-i\beta$. The residues evaluation is straightforward and gives
$$J(\alpha)\Big(1-e^{2\pi p}\Big)=2\pi i\left(\frac{e^{p\beta}\cos\beta}{\sinh(i\beta)}+\frac{e^{2\pi p-p\beta}\cos\beta}{\sinh(-i\beta)}\right)$$
Using $\sinh(i\beta)=i\sin\beta$ and coming back to $\alpha=\arccos\beta$
$$J(\alpha)=\frac{2\pi\alpha}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}}\,\frac{\sinh\big(p(\pi-\arccos\alpha)\big)}{\sinh(\pi p)}$$
Taking derivatives with respect to $\alpha$, we can find $I_n$:
$$I_1=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh u}du=\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}J(\alpha)\,\bigg|_{\alpha=0}=2\pi\frac{\sinh\frac{\pi p}2}{\sinh(\pi p)}=\frac\pi{\cosh\frac{\pi p}2}$$
$$I_2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh^2u}du=\frac12\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\alpha^2}J(\alpha)\,\bigg|_{\alpha=0}=2\pi p\,\frac{\cosh\frac{\pi p}2}{\sinh(\pi p)}=\frac{\pi p}{\sinh\frac{\pi p}2}$$
etc.
In our evaluations we did not define the sign of $p$, so the expression is valid for positive and negative $p$ (and for $p=0$, of course - we just have to take the limit $p\to0$)

To evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh^2(u)} \, du,
$$
we consider the complex function $f(z) = \frac{e^{-ipz}}{\cosh^2(z)}$ and use the method of residues.
Case 1: $p > 0$
For $p > 0$, we close the contour in the upper half-plane with a semi-circular path at infinity. The function $f(z)$ has poles where $\cosh^2(z) = 0$. These occur at $z = \frac{(2n+1)\pi i}{2}$, where $n$ is an integer. Among these, only $z = \frac{\pi i}{2}$ lies within our contour for the upper half-plane. The residue at this pole is computed as follows:
$$
\text{Res}(f, \frac{\pi i}{2}) = \lim_{z \to \frac{\pi i}{2}} \frac{e^{-ipz}}{\left(\frac{d}{dz}\cosh^2(z)\right)_{z=\frac{\pi i}{2}}}
$$
Given $\frac{d}{dz}\cosh^2(z) = 2\cosh(z)\sinh(z)$, and noting that $\cosh(\frac{\pi i}{2}) = 0$, we find the residue is:
$$
\text{Res}(f, \frac{\pi i}{2}) = \frac{e^{-\frac{\pi p}{2}i}}{2i\sinh(\frac{\pi i}{2})}
$$
Applying the Residue Theorem:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ipu}}{\cosh^2(u)} \, du = 2\pi i \cdot \text{Res}(f, \frac{\pi i}{2})
$$
Case 2: $p < 0$
For $p < 0$, we close the contour in the lower half-plane. Similar to the first case, the relevant pole in the lower half-plane is at $z = -\frac{\pi i}{2}$. The calculation of the residue and the integral follows similarly, considering the appropriate sign for $p$ and the placement of the pole.

Can you please help me by providing the steps of residue calculations?
